# Simple horizontal path

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, arrows

I am trying to create just a simple horizontal arrow (line 1) from Advertiser to Scanner above line 2 in a certain distance. Since too much time I am trying to find out the right grammatics but without success. I am very grateful for any help.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, 
    block_center/.style ={rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=white,text width=12em, text centered, minimum height=12em}, 

\matrix [column sep=30mm,row sep=30mm] {  
      \node [block_center] (Scanner) {\textbf{Scanner}} ; 
    & \node  [block_center] (Advertiser) {\textbf{Advertiser}} ; \\
}; % end matrix  

\path [draw, ->] (Advertiser.west)+(0,1.5) -- node [midway,above] {line 1}  (Scanner);
  \path [draw, ->] (Advertiser.west)         -- node [midway,above] {line 2}  (Scanner) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete compilable example, also known as, Minimum Working Example (MWA).

Answer (score 4):

Two options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
auto, 
block_center/.style ={
  rectangle,
  draw=black,
  thick,
  fill=white,
  text width=12em,
  text centered,
  minimum height=12em
}
]
\matrix [column sep=30mm,row sep=30mm] 
{  
  \node [block_center] (Scanner) {\textbf{Scanner}} ; 
  & \node  [block_center] (Advertiser) {\textbf{Advertiser}} ; \\
}; % end matrix  

\draw[->] ([yshift=10pt]Advertiser.west) -- node [midway,above] {line 1}  ([yshift=10pt]Scanner.east|-Advertiser.west);
\draw[->] (Advertiser.160) -- node [midway,above] {line 0}  (Scanner.east|-Advertiser.160);
\draw[->] (Advertiser.west) -- node [midway,above] {line 2}  (Scanner) ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A simpler diagram for the explanation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,minimum size=2cm] (A) {A};
\node[draw,minimum size=2cm,right=2cm of A] (B) {B};
\draw (A.10) -- (B.west|-A.10);
\draw ([yshift=-20pt]A.east) -- ([yshift=-20pt]B.west|-A.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In both cases, the key is the use of the perpendicular coordinate system. The synatx `(<name1>|-<name2>)` gives the coordinate having the `x`-coordinate of `<name1>` and the `y`-coordinate of `<name2>`.

Saying

```
\draw (A.10) -- (B.west|-A.10);
```

means "draw a line from `A.10` to the point having the `x`-coordinate of `B.west` and the `y`-coordinate of `A.10`" (this guarantees that the line will be horizontal.)

Analogously,

```
\draw ([yshift=-20pt]A.east) -- ([yshift=-20pt]B.west|-A.east);
```

means "draw a line from `A.east`, shifted `20pt` downwards, to the point having the `x`-coordinate of `B.west` and the `y`-coordinate of `A.east`, and shifted shifted `20pt` downwards" (again, this guarantees that the line will be horizontal.)

Theres also the syntax `(<name1>-|<name2>)`; it's a homework to read about its meaning in the PGF manual.